# Как отследить автоподстановку пароля в браузере?

Tags: javascript, html5, frontend, webbrowser, material-design

У меня элементы ввода сделаны как вот здесь - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gEZoNY?&editable=true&editors=101.

```
<div id="app">
```

```
      <v-flex xs12 sm6>
        <v-text-field
          :type="'text'"
          name="login"
          label="логин"
          hint="At least 8 characters"
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="password"
          :append-icon="show1 ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'"
          :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
          :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
          name="input-10-1"
          label="Normal with hint text"
          hint="At least 8 characters"
          counter
          @click:append="show1 = !show1"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>




    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</v-form>
```

*Т.е. изначально label находится, как бы, внутри элемента ввода, а когда пользователь по нему кликает, или как либо его заполнил, то label отодвигаетия и поялвяется ввод. (см пример в codepen).*

**Всё работает хорошо, но ровно до тех пор пока пока логин и пароль не подставляет из автозаполнения менеджера паролей браузера**

Как только это происходит (*можно проверить в примере, для этого нужно на этой форме в codepen вбить любую ерунду и сохраить её в менджере паролей браузера, а потом вновь открыть эту страницу*) То подставленный браузером пароль наезжает на label т.е. лэйбел как бы не получает изначально событие Input, и лэйбел не отодвигается.

**Подскажите пожалуйста,как можно это исправить?**

**Может быть можно как то отследить, когда браузер что либо подставляет в input, а когда нет?**

Comment: а почему бы не проверить поле по таймауту, после загрузки?

Comment: Не получается, хоть визуально поле и заполнено браузером, но по факту его инпут пуст, пока пользователь куда нибудь, не кликнет, а иначе label сам бы отьехал. По крайней мере у меня это так работало, точнее не работало, когда я с таймаутом пытался проверять, может я что то не так делал?

Comment: Самый простой способ это ввести данные и сохранить в браузере когда сам это предлагает, если при submit не выходит окошко то поищите это в YouTube